What prevents "/usr/sbin/ip netns exec some-ns /usr/sbin/mount.cifs" from working?
Why changing the network namespace is not enough to mount a network share with a different view of the network stack?
It surprises me that the same thing is possible through (privileged) containers - which also use a separate network namespace (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40330794/361806).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The devs may be able to answer what is preventing this from working as you expect. This site is more about specific and practical questions, so maybe consider rephrasing this post to focus on the specific question you're facing, and present that in a practical and pragmatic way.
